# How to use dependency injection in Automapper 12.x ConstructUsing

Tags: c#, nhibernate, automapper

We are using Automapper to map DTOs to entities.

To make sure that the created entity is always bound to the session (we use NHibernate), we have the following in the Automapper configuration:

```
var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    // Do other stuff
    cfg.Internal().ForAllMaps((tm, me) =>
    {
        if (typeof(IEntity).IsAssignableFrom(tm.DestinationType) &&
            typeof(IHasId).IsAssignableFrom(tm.SourceType))
        {
            var entityResolverType = typeof(EntityResolver<,>).MakeGenericType(tm.SourceType, tm.DestinationType);
            me.ConstructUsing((source, context) =>
            {
                var resolver = context.Options.ServiceCtor.Invoke(entityResolverType) as IEntityResolver;
                return resolver.Resolve(source);
            });
        }
    });
    cfg.AllowNullDestinationValues = true;
});
```

Now in Automapper 12.x there is no more access to the `ServiceCtor` in the `ResolutionContext` and we have to think of another solution.

I have written an `ITypeConverter`. But here the problem is that after creating the entity the properties are not mapped.

If I use

```
public class EntityTypeConverter<TModel, TEntity> : ITypeConverter<TModel, TEntity>
    where TModel : IHasId
    where TEntity : IEntity
{
    private readonly ISession session;

    public EntityTypeConverter(ISession session) { this.session = session; }

    public TEntity Convert(TModel source, TEntity destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (destination is null)
        {
            destination = session.Get<TEntity>(source.Id);
            destination ??= Activator.CreateInstance<TEntity>();
        }

        context.Mapper.Map(source, destination);
        return destination;
    }
}
```

I get into an infinite loop.

I can't use `AfterMap` either, because it is a void method and the entity is not passed by ref. Thus, I could load the entity, but the Automapper would still return the unbound instance.

A third solution would be to pass the session to the `Mapper.Map` in the options and then access it via `Mapper.Items`. But for this I would have to adapt a lot of code lines and it is also not guaranteed that in the future every programmer will remember to do this.

I don't understand why this is so complicated. Is this such an unusual approach to write a generic class that loads the appropriate entity from the session/dbContext for each DTO, and only then maps the new values from the DTO into the entity?

Does anyone have any idea how I can implement this with DTO, constructor, scope and bound entity?

Thanks for Help.

Comment: How this usually works is that you pass the destination to `Map`.

Comment: There ks also [ConstructUsingServiceLocator](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/104a192407858fe3a54a8a937ca95a34fd7c6959/src/AutoMapper/Configuration/IMappingExpressionBase.cs#L68.)

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu but how can i pass the Id on ConstructUsingServiceLocator?

Comment: There is no id in the `ConstructUsing` above.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu but source (model) which is IHasId.

Comment: Then you're back to the first solution. We'll take a PR to add a class based `ConstructUsing`. Otherwise, you have to solve that in your own code.